# WebStorm re-indexing monorepo

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, monorepo, rush

I am working on a huge monorepo application. They use rush and pnpm as monorepo manager.

When I open project or checkout a branch or run `rush update`, because of many file changes. My IDE goes slow and consume a lot of CPU for **indexing**

How can I make it faster?

Comment: 1) Try marking unwanted folders as Excluded. The IDE may still check/index them but they will not be used for code completion and alike. 2) If a folder name is unique, add it into `Exclude files` list (on `Settings/Preferences | Directories` screen); such files and folders than match those patterns will not be shown in the Project View and should be completely ignored. That's all what I may say for now.

Comment: Unfortunately we have few unwanted folders. The project is very big monorepo with more than 100 packages. It is almost 100 project in a single project. The developers who use vscode as their IDE have no similar issues and the work blazing fast

Comment: It's fast because it doesn't index the project > it doesn't know about its structure. Indexing in PhpStorm is required to provide you with the correct completion suggestions for your project. IDE tries to utilize all of the available CPU resources to finish indexing asap. I'm afraid this is an unavoidable downtime, if you need code completion based on objects inside the monorepo libraries. How long does indexing takes after typical changes?